# What's the idiomatic way to control a nested UIView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, swiftui

I want to show a WKWebView in a SwiftUI view hierarchy, and I want to control the WKWebView using buttons implemented in SwiftUI.

I can do this by creating a SwiftUI `WebView` class that implements `UIViewRepresentable` and wraps `WKWebView`, like so...

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> WKWebView {
    return WKWebView(frame: .zero)
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
    // Update WKWebView here if necessary
  }
}
```

...and then using it as follows...

```
struct BrowserView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      WebView()

      // Footer
      HStack {
        Button(action: {
          // When this is called, I want to somehow call .goBack()
          // on the WKWebView.
        }) {
          Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
        }

        ...
      } // HStack
    } // VStack
  }
}
```

When the user taps the Button, I want to somehow call `goBack` on the `WKWebView`. How am I to do this idiomatically in SwiftUI?

Approaches I've considered that I think are either brittle or aren't idiomatic SwiftUI...

- Represent the number of times that a user has clicked "Back" in a binding. Have WebView listen to that binding and move back when that increments.
- Have `BrowserView` create an object called something like `MutableWebViewAPI` and pass it to `WebView` on construction. `WebView` listens on this object so that when `BrowserView` calls something like `MutableWebViewAPI.goBack()`, `WebView` does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to leverage the power of Combine by creating a `PassthroughSubject` on your parent view and then subscribe to events in your child `WebView`.

First, create a struct in your `UIViewReprsentable` that captures the available events you want to send to your `WebView`:

```swift
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    enum WebEvent {
        case back
        case forward
    }

    let eventPublisher: AnyPublisher<WebEvent, Never>

    init(eventPublisher: AnyPublisher<WebEvent, Never>) {
        self.eventPublisher = eventPublisher

        eventPublisher.sink { event in
            // forward the appropriate event to your underlying WKWebView
        }
    }
}
```

Next, in your parent, create the `PassthroughSubject` to create these events.

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    private let eventSender = PassthroughSubject<WebView.WebEvent, Never>()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Back") {
                self.eventSender.send(.back)
            }
            Button("Forward") {
                self.eventSender.send(.forward)
            }

            WebView(eventPublisher: eventSender.eraseToAnyPublisher())
        }
    }
}
```